# Can I disable the HSQLDB init script creation?

Tags: security, hsqldb

HQSLDB creates a *database*.script file with the DDL SQL statements to setup the database and then the DML SQL statements, all to reconstruct the database I'm guessing.

My problem is that the script file has sensitive data exposed in clear text.

My question is, can the creation of that file be disabled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The .script file is created for file: databases (persistent). Alternatively you can create a mem: database, which does not store the data on disk (the data disappears when the Java process exits).

You can also create a file: database with encryption. The .script file as well as the .log and .data files are stored in encrypted format.

See http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/management-chapt.html for details.

Comment: I need to persist the data so, in this case I can't use a mem database, but the database with encryption seems to fit the bill.  Thanks.